# PyQt4 Import Error

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I have downloaded PyQt4 and have been able to use it without any issues in Idle. However, when I am trying to execute a command in terminal, I am receiving the error

```
ImportError: No module named PyQt4
```

[image]

The code I ran is the following:

```
User-MacBook-Pro:Python $ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
User-MacBook-Pro:Python $ pyuic4 Print.ui>Print_ui.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/uic/pyuic.py", line 26, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtCore
ImportError: No module named PyQt4
```

I would love to get some guidance on this issue.

Thank you

Comment: Is the header that prints in IDLE (`Python 2.7.10 ...`) the same as the header that prints when you run `python` from the command line? It's possible IDLE is using the system Python (`/usr/bin/python`), while the command line is using the Python.org version.

Comment: It is the same in both versions, the terminal version is as `Python 2.7.10 (v2.7.10:15c95b7d81dc, May 23 2015, 09:33:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`

Comment: Are you sure about the command you are executing?...because I believe the way it's supposed to be is: `pyuic4.exe input.ui -o output.py` ?.. correct me if I'm wrong..

Comment: So I was able to make it work. I am not quite sure how. I downloaded  `sudo port install py27-pyqt4` and it is now working in terminal. And Khalil, I believe that command works on windows not OS.

Comment: Ok...Good for you...the command I posted, I used it for Linux System (Ubuntu...)..

Comment: Thank you! I will try it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved the same problems, I find that the problem is in file 'pyuic4'. The wrong version python was setted.

You can run code--`which pyuic4`--to find where is the pyuic4, and then open this file by texteditor(eg.Sublime Text). After that, you will find one row code in this file:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec pythonw2.7 //anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/uic/pyuic.py ${1+"$@"}
```

So, the function of `pyuic4` is to call pythonw2.7 and run `pyuic.py`.

In my computer, I have installed `anaconda` so the PyQt4 file is stored in anaconda PATH, but `pythonw2.7` will use the Apple supplid Python. Under the circumstance, pythonw2.7 can't import the module PyQt4. Changing it to `pythonw` which belongs to anaconda will solve the problem.

In your problem, I think you can check out the python version, and change the default version of pythonw in `pyuic.py` to right version.

Just use pythonw to run the following file:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/uic/pyuic.py
```

If the return result is:

```
Error: one input ui-file must be specified
```

rather than:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/uic/pyuic.py", line 26, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtCore
ImportError: No module named PyQt4
```

the pythonw is the right version.

Comment: Oh wow, I havent looked at this in quite some time. I went the much more difficult route of resetting my computer, and somehow everything has been working perfectly. This definitely would've been helpful then haha

Comment: Wow, my origin plan was to reset my python, but  I find that the problem is in file 'pyuic4' at last.